# Cannot send value to paypal

Tags: paypal

PayPal IPN sends a notification to your script directly. Since the notification is coming from PayPal - NOT the customer that placed the order - My Login session doesn't exits this context .Therefore,all my login data doesn't exist in the session.I need my login session values to update my DB with paypal ipn value.How should i mentain my login session should i set browser session or other way can i send login primary key to paypal.

Comment: You should add the language you're using to the tags

Answer (score 0):

The Paypal IPN allows you to pass a `custom` field in your form (you could put your session ID in that) and then then IPN will pass that along to your script. (Or why not just pass the userid or whatever key in the request itself)?